# How to access chrome.runtime in options page in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to create option page in chrome extension development and this is the manifest :

```
"manifest_version": 1,
"author":"Handita Okviyanto",
"name": "My Extension",
"options_page": "home.html",
```

And then I want to access `chrome.runtime` in my `home.html`
the file look like this :

```
<html>
....
<script src="app.js">
....
</html>
```

And the `app.js` look like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = chrome.runtime.getUrl('login.html');
});
```

But when I debug through the chrome developer  the result is `undefined`. I can access this through the `background.js` or `contentscript.js`

[image: image chrome]

I'm still confuse in what page should I use `chrome` object.

## updated

The additional image
[image: chrome undefined]

Comment: Don't set breakpoints before the first access to chrome API. It's a known bug.

Comment: Oke. I try to move the code up outsite jquery ready function. But I still can not access the function. It states that function `getUrl` is not defined. How can I access it? `app.js:1103 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUrl' of undefined
    at app.js:1103`

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but there is no `getUrl` method. It should be `getURL`.

Comment: Sory for wrong type. But when I change into `getURL` it still undefined. variable `chrome` has value `'Google Chrome'` string type instead when I debug

Comment: You're overwriting `chrome` API with the result. Rename your variable to something else.

Comment: tha'ts not the problem with the variable. I also rename to another name, the problem still exists

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm. Finally I found the problem, I included the library with global variable name `chrome` so it's overrided by the variable. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem, I included the library with global variable name `chrome` so it's overrided by the variable.

so I just search all the variable named chrome through all files. And found chrome in one of the file js I have included.